# Pre disable an input filed after loading page with jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to see pre disabled input field right after loading the page. Here the input field will be disabled though a selected option.

```
window.onload=function(){
    $('#account').on('load', function(){
        if($(this).val() === 'Asset')
        {
            $("#debit").prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
}
```

Assuming that option is selected when page loaded.

Comment: Input will be disabled at page load or through selected option? Explain your question.

Comment: Selected option is pre selected during page load, which I have done already. I need pre selected input field base on selected option.

Comment: For simplicity,
#account: <select> id;
Asset: <Option> value;
#debit: <input> id;